# How can I insert text behind the specified character in Vim?

Tags: vim

Here is the raw material I’m working with:

```
First.   
This is the second line.   
The third.
```

I want to insert  "insert something behind 4 character" in the text, to make it become

```
Firsinsert something behind 4 charactert.   
Thisinsert something behind 4 character is the second line.   
The insert something behind 4 characterthird.
```

---

```
:%s/^.\{4}/insert something behind 4 character/g
```

The `substitute` command does not insert text. How can I insert this string behind the 4th character of every line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very close.  Just tell vim to start substituting at the **end** of the pattern:

```
:%s/^.\{4}\zs/insert something behind 4 character/
```

Note that I left off the `g` flag:  it does not make a difference here, since the pattern will not match more than once in a line.

Of course, there are other ways to do it, such as

```
:%s/^.\{4}/&insert something behind 4 character/
```

That is, replace the first four characters with a copy of themselves followed by the new text.  Or

```
:%s/\%5c\@=/insert something behind 4 character/
```

or

```
:%s/\%5c\&/insert something behind 4 character/
```

(The last two will not work if there are only 4 characters on the line.)

```
:help sub-replace-special
:help /\zs
:help /\&
:help /\%c
:help /\@=
```

and, in general,

```
:help pattern
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `&` to match to insert the matched part

```
:%s/^.\{4}/&insert something behind 4 character/g
```

Answer (score 3):

Since others have suggested how to do this with replace, I'll mention visual mode as an alternative:

1. Place cursor on `t` in `First`.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to enter visual mode.
3. <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> to move down two lines.
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to insert.
5. Type your message. It will appear to only be inserting on the first line.
6. <kbd>Escape</kbd> to insert what you typed into the three selected lines.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following regex, you will be able to accomplish to insert starting from the fourth character of every line.

`:%s/\(^.\{4}\)/\1insert something behind 4 character/g`